# Python requests, can't log into a site

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to use Python (3.2) requests to login to a site and navigate protected content on subsequent pages. However, when I login it seems to just leave me at the original login page (not navigating to the success page), and the subsequent page call is only showing the unprotected content. Can you please help me identify the bug in my code:

```
import requests
import sys

class login:
    def __init__(self):
        self.payload = None
        self.c = None

    def start(self,username,password,loginpage):
        self.payload = {'login':username,'password':password}
        self.loginpage = loginpage

    def login(self,url):
        self.c = requests.session()
        response = self.c.post(self.loginpage,data=self.payload)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            request = self.c.get(url)
            print(request.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    username = 'username'
    password = "password"
    loginpage = "https://www.clubfreetime.com/login/"
    nextpage = "http://www.clubfreetime.com/new-york-city-nyc/free-theater-performances-shows"
    login = login()
    login.start(username,password,loginpage)
    login.login(nextpage)
```

Comment: First see if the post request made was authenticated. `login_request = self.c.post(self.loginpage,data=self.payload)`.
And check the value of `login_request.status_code` and `login_request.text`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you didnt check if the post you made is ok ; you just continue with a get, so this call is not linked to the previous request and then it of course continues

for example :

```
def login(self,url):
    self.c = requests.session()
    # test if the post is ok with your business process
    if self.c.post(self.loginpage,data=self.payload) == whateveryourneed:
       request = self.c.get(url)
       print(request.text)
```

this answer is not THE answer but just a way to try to show you the step you seemed to miss

hope this help ;)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! It helped me get in the right direction, but I'm not quite there yet. I tried checking the response and my login_request is equal to 200, but the login_request.text is the same login page were I initiated the request. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I needed to change self.payload to:
self.payload = {'login':username,'password':password,'submit_login':'Login'}